# Need to click on specific link using selenium in Firefox browser

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm using selenium with the Firefox browser. I need to click on the href link associated with the text 'GS-L1' in HTML like what appears below. How can I do that? In spite of various approaches my efforts have always met with "Exception Type   : selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException\nException Detail : Message: Unable to locate element".

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<h3 class="header smaller lighter green" style="font-family:Arial;">Application Health Check</h3>
<p></p>
<a href="link1" class="btn btn-app btn-primary" title="NDS Level-1 Healthcheck">
<i class="ace-icon fa fa-sitemap bigger-230 faa-vertical animated "></i>
NDS-L1
</a>
<a href="link2" class="btn btn-app btn-purple" title="GS Level-1 Healthcheck">
<center><i class="ace-icon fa fa-refresh bigger-230 fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i></center>
GS-L1
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here are some of the attempts I've made:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("index.htm")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_id("CID").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_name("password1").send_keys("psd")
driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[text()="GS-L1"]')[1].click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="GS Level-1 Healthcheck"][@text="GS-L1"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="http://sample.co.za/GS_HealthCheck.htm"][@title="GS Level-1 Healthcheck"]')[1]
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="ace-icon fa fa-refresh bigger-230 fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"][@title="GS Level-1 Healthcheck"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="http://sample.co.za/GS_HealthCheck.htm"]')[1]
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="GS Level-1 Healthcheck"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'GS-L1')]").click()
driver.find_elements_by_class('ace-icon fa fa-refresh bigger-230 fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw')[0]
datentime = driver.findElement(By.className("ace-icon fa fa-refresh bigger-230 fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw")).find_element_by_link_text("GS-L1")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("GS-L1")[1].click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("GS-L1")[1]
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Selfie - Support Automation")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
elem.click()

click_element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("GS-L1")
click_element.click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.linkText, "GS-L1")))
```

Comment: could you please write the html page url ?

Comment: chop out extraneous verbiage

Comment: Are your sure you no need to wait for page loading after this line: driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()

Comment: no not necessary #yong.. that URL cannot be viewed from outside networks.. #Reza

Comment: At what point in your above code are you getting the mentioned exception?

Comment: From line number 8 to 16th.. I'm trying to do the same.. I use to comment all these lines except any one of them while executing.. even in 20th line i tried the same.. none of them are working but showing the same error..

Comment: I would suggest you to use javascript executor in this situation. Something like - `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="GS Level-1 Healthcheck"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`. Lets see if it works.